# Could any give an idea to code : Way of converting ( set of string to set of ID )

Tags: apex

Tried this but it didn't worked :

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>{'001C000001DgWjE','001C000001DgWjD'};


Set<String> idStrs = (Set<String>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(ids), Set<String>.class);

System.debug('idStrings=' + idStrs);
```

Please Help

Comment: What do you want to achieve? convert set of strings to set of ids?
if yes, then Set<Id> idsSet = (Set<Id>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(id), Set<Id>.class);

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
Set<String> stringIds = new Set<String>{'001C000001DgWjE','001C000001DgWjD'};
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
for (String stringId : stringIds) {
    Id stringToId = Id.valueOf(stringId);
    ids.add(strintToId);
}
```

Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the type without the loop:

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>{'001C000001DgWjE','001C000001DgWjD'};
Set<String> idStrs = new Set<String>( (List<String>) new List<Id>(ids) );
```

or like so:

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>{'001C000001DgWjE','001C000001DgWjD'};
List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>(ids);
List<String> listStrs = (List<String>) listIds;
Set<String> setIds = new Set<String>(listIds);
```